# CSS - Box Model - Works only in Chrome

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

After creating a simple fluid layout with Bootstrap's css, I've noticed that the layout does not line up on the right side on **every browser except Chrome**.

Take a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/47JND/5/  on, for example, firefox or IE9.

You'll notice this:

[image]

It is only about a 1px difference between Chrome, (see below):

[image]

Notice also that I am using the following box-sizing property:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

Is there something I am missing? I've tried everything I can think of to figure out what is causing this!

Comment: The red circle almost makes it harder to notice the miss-alignment. I'd make it larger next time.

Comment: The problem is that this is being zoomed in photoshop.  Any more zoom and you would see less.

Comment: Works fine in all versions of IE...

Comment: Works fine in FF and IE9 for me ...

Comment: I did not mean make the image larger but just the red circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly sure this is a sub-pixel rendering issue. The width is being rounded to the nearest pixel which makes them different widths based on the width of the parent.

Im seeing the 1 pixel overlap on Chrome too.

Comment: I think you're right since I resized Firefox's browser and it lined up nicely.  Same for IE.  I appreciate the help!